# How do I write a sub-query?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, titan

I want to retrieve all vertexes and for each one I want to count the number of 'Like' edges pointing at it.

How do I write this kind of query in Gremlin?

In SQL it could be something like....

```
SELECT *, (SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl_like l WHERE l.id = b.id) AS LikeCount
FROM tbl_blah b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a side effect...

```
g.V().transform{[it, it.in('likes').count()]}
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g. use `sideEffect` to put the counts in a map (`m`)

```
m=[:];g.V.sideEffect{m[it]=it.inE.has('label','like').count()}
```

An alternative which omits vertices with 0 likes:

```
m=[:];g.V.inE('like').groupCount(m){it.inV.next()}
```

**EDIT**

Finally the smart solution:

```
 m=[:];g.V.groupCount(m){it}{it.a.inE('like').count()}
```

The first closure of `groupCount` determines the key to update in the map and the second closure the value to the key. Seems like `it.a` in the second closure gives the current input value to `groupCount` (here a vertex) and `it.b` the previous value in the map for the input object. Haven't really found a documentation that explains this, maybe one of the TinkerPop guys can elaborate on the exact usage of the `groupCount` closures.

Comment: You're right, the `b` is the previous value returned from the closure.  In that way you can increment `b` over each item that passes through the `groupCount`.  In this case, that isn't necessary, because the edge count is all you want.

Comment: Where is the documentation for the map declaration? I can't see it here... http://gremlindocs.com/

Comment: Your first solution works good but it took me a while to find a way of returning the info. This works, what do you think....? m=[:];g.V().sideEffect({m[it] = it.in().has('type').count()}).transform{[it, m[it]]}

Comment: How can I return a map in order to give the values names?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider:

```
m = g.E.has('label','like').groupBy{it.inV.next()}{1}{it.sum()}.cap.next()
```

Iterate all edges and filter by label, group on the `inV` of each "like" edge and add a `1` to that `Map` of results.  That much takes you to the second to last closure of the `groupBy`.  At that point you will have a `Map` like:

```
[v1:[1,1,1]
 v2:[1,1]]
```

which basically is a vertex with a 1 representing each "like" edge.  Going back to the Gremlin above, the final closure to `groupBy` is a reduce operation that occurs on the values in the `Map`.  In this case, we use the Groovy `sum` function (though I suppose `size` would work here too - but `sum` seems easier for readability) to add up the number of edges.  Finally, we use `cap` to extract the `Map` side-effect from the pipeline and `next` it out into a var.

I suppose the downside here is that it doesn't yield a result for vertices with no "like" edges.  If you need that, then the solution provided by @Faber is a better way to go.  You might even pick and choose a bit from both solutions to ultimately get at what you are looking for.

Comment: Finally I understand `cap`. From the doc: "`cap` emits the value of the previous step (here the map resulting from `groupBy`) and not the values that flow through it (here edges that flow through `groupBy`)"! Thx! But hence `cap` behaves like `gather` in that it collects all objects up to the `cap` step, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go that far. `cap` simply extracts the side-effect from the previous step, whereas `gather` works on objects in the pipeline itself, grabbing all items in the pipeline to a list.  One works with pipeline objects and one grabs side-effects....it's an important distinction.