# How to get multiple vertices/edges in a single gremlin query?

Tags: titan, gremlin, bulbs

I am in a situation where I need to get two different types of vertices using a single query. For example, assume that the graph has the following structure :

```
Node("User")--Edge("is_member")-->Node("Membership")--Edge("is_member")-->Node("Group")
```

Assume that the nodes have the following properties:

1. Membership

   - status
   - date
2. Group

   - name
   - date
   - type

Now, I need to get all the `Membership` nodes that a user `is_member` of, along with the corresponding `Group`'s `name`. How do I write a Gremlin query for this?

I am using the Bulbs framework. How do I store the result in a python object?

Comment: Are you sure that you need a Node for 'Membership'? … to me that rather sounds like a type of edge. You can also have properties on edges.

Comment: @Faber I felt that adding `membership` as a node could help me later to make interesting relations like, liking the fact that a user is a member of a group, commenting on it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gives you for user `u1` a map with `key = Membership-Node`s and `value = list of group names of the key membership node`:

```
m=[:];u1.out('is_member').groupBy(m){it}{it.out('is_member').name}
```

Output is:

```
gremlin> m
==>v[m1]=[group1]
==>v[m2]=[group2, group3]
```

Here the used sample graph:

```
g = new TinkerGraph()
u1 = g.addVertex('u1')
u2 = g.addVertex('u2')
m1 = g.addVertex('m1')
m2 = g.addVertex('m2')
g1 = g.addVertex('g1')
g2 = g.addVertex('g2')
g3 = g.addVertex('g3')

g.addEdge(u1, m1, 'is_member')
g.addEdge(u1, m2, 'is_member')
g.addEdge(u2, m2, 'is_member')
g.addEdge(m1, g1, 'is_member')
g.addEdge(m2, g2, 'is_member')
g.addEdge(m2, g3, 'is_member')

g1.name = 'group1'
g2.name = 'group2'
g3.name = 'group3'
```

See also: [How do I write a sub-query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734657/how-do-i-write-a-sub-query/26735686#26735686)

(tested with gremlin2)

Comment: So, I assume that the returned value in Python using Bulbs is a generator of dictionary, right?

Comment: Maybe something like a generator of key-value-pairs? … I've never used bulps, sorry. http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/gremlin/